# JWT decode() must be of the type array error

Tags: php, jwt, slim

Here I have some slim PHP code which is log in and a function to check whether it decode the JWT that store in the header.

```
$app->post('/login', function ($request, $response) {

$input = $request->getParsedBody();
$settings = $this->get('settings'); // get settings array.
$sql = "SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE id= :id";
$sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam("id", $input['id']);
$sth->execute();
$user = $sth->fetchObject();

// verify user id 
if(!$user) {
    return $this->response->withJson(['error' => true, 'message' => 'NO ID '], 404)->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8', 404);
}
// Compare the input password and the password from database for a validation
if (strcmp($input['password'],$user->password)) {
    return $this->response->withJson(['error' => true, 'message' => 'These credentials do not match our records.'], 404)->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8', 404);  
}

$payload = array(
    "iat" => time(),
    "exp" => time() + 36000,
    // "id" => $input['id']
    "context" => [
        "user" => [
            "id" => $input['id']
        ]
    ]
);

try {
    $token = JWT::encode($payload, $settings['jwt']['secret'],"HS256"); // $token store the token of the user
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode($e);
}


return $this->response->withJson($payload,200)
                      ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8', 200)
                      ->withAddedHeader('Authorization', $token);
});


$app->get('/get', function ($request, $response) {

$jwt = $request->getHeader("Authorization"); 
$settings = $this->get('settings'); 

$token = JWT::decode($jwt, $settings['jwt']['secret'], "HS256"); // $token store the token of the user

if ($token) {
    return $this->response->withJson($token, 200)
    ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8', 200);
}

return $this->response->withJson($token,401)
                      ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8', 401);

});
```

But it when i try to run http://localhost:8080/get it returns an error which is

> Argument 3 passed to Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode() must be of the type array.

Why does it happen and how can i fix it?

Comment: **Warning!** `strcmp($input['password'],$user->password)` suggests that you're not properly hashing the passwords. You should _always_ use [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) when dealing with passwords. _Never_ store them as plain text or use any self-built hashing algorithm.

Comment: Yeah i know, I'm not doing for production. Will implement security later on. Thank you

Comment: what does the `print_r($settings);` show? try to debug it

Comment: it is my jwt setting that contain the key, see my new comment

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow what the error says:

```
$token = JWT::decode($jwt, $settings['jwt']['secret'], ["HS256"]);
```

You can see the Example of using [here](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt)

Comment: still the same error, btw this is the bit of the error https://imgur.com/a/wMhwAAm

Comment: it does say something like Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode(Array, 'supersecretkeyy...', Array) with ur code . But with my code, its say Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode(Array, 'supersecretkeyy...', "HS256")

Comment: The key error is `Wrong number of segments`, your token is not a valid JWT, please print what you are passing into `decode` function

Comment: Please accept the best answer if this helped to solve the problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

If i decode in the same function it returns the decoded JWT, but if i decode in other function it returns an error. How to pass the jwt to other function?

```
$app->post('/login', function ($request, $response) {

$key = "supersecretkeyyoushouldnotcommittogithub";

$input = $request->getParsedBody();
$settings = $this->get('settings'); // get settings array.
$sql = "SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE id= :id";
$sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindParam("id", $input['id']);
$sth->execute();
$user = $sth->fetchObject();

// verify user id 
if(!$user) {
    return $this->response->withJson(['error' => true, 'message' => 'NO ID '], 404)->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8', 404);
}
// Compare the input password and the password from database for a validation
if (strcmp($input['password'],$user->password)) {
    return $this->response->withJson(['error' => true, 'message' => 'These credentials do not match our records.'], 404)->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8', 404);  
}

$payload = array(
    "iat" => time(),
    "exp" => time() + 36000,
    // "id" => $input['id']
    "context" => [
        "user" => [
            "id" => $input['id']
        ]
    ]
);

try {
    $token = JWT::encode($payload, $key); // $token store the token of the user
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode($e);
}

// return $this->response->withJson($payload,200)
//                       ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8', 200)
//                       ->withHeader('Authorization', $token);

$decoded = JWT::decode($token, $key, array('HS256'));

print_r($decoded);


});
```

Comment: As I wrote, your token is invalid when you do a request, print `$jwt` variable after `$jwt = $request->getHeader("Authorization"); ` line.

Comment: Edit your question please and don't post an updated question as an answer.

Comment: yeah, my jwt is empty.

Comment: @pr1nc3 ok, sorry quite new to stack